# Copying a file results in java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is Denied) from output

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

```
File file1 = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "/example/directory/example.png");
file1.mkdirs();
file1.setWritable(true);
file1.createNewFile();
try {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(exampleInputDirectory);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    FileChannel srcChannel = is.getChannel();
    FileChannel dstChannel = os.getChannel();
    dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());
    is.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my setup for copying an image file to a new directory tree.  However, when this code is executed I get the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: *points to output directory* (Access is denied)
```

Have I gone about creating `file1` incorrectly?

Comment: You wrote, in the first line `file.getAbsoluteFile()`. Do you have another variable named file, or did you mean `file1`?

Comment: is the file being used ? do you have permission to access to that path?

Comment: have updated the answer, have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is because of using

```
file1.mkdirs();
```

and

```
file1.createNewFile();
```

together.

Since the `file1` object is already been given 'directory' attributes after creating it as directory by calling "file1.mkdirs()", but then you are again using the same object to create a 'file', that means changin attribute of file1 object from directory to a file, which is not allowed. that's why its giving you `FileNotFound`.

Comment: I got rid of the mkdirs call.  Now it's giving me  `java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified` on file1.  Should I be making the directory *then* make the file?

Comment: @JeffDemanche yes, since createNewFile() will only create a New File. But if path is not existent, it wont create directories. Thats why its giving this error now. So make sure the folder you are trying to put the file in, exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your creation of file1 seems to be up to par, maybe your input dir is non existent?  Make sure all caps and such are correct, and that there are no typos in your directory reference.  Also be sure if the user has permissions to copy a file to the directory, if not you can run it as root in linux, and as administrative in windows.